# Support export to Word format for CV's created by careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv, export

I've really only just begun to play with careers and it really a joy to use. However having as been on both sides of the recruitment fence, the only format recruiters speak is **Word**

I the past I tried giving recruiters CV's in PDF format or links to my own online CV in HTML, but the vast majority of them reject it out of hand and ask for a Word (doc or docx) format.

- **Removing information**: A lot of recruiters will *remove candidates personal information*, email address, phone number etc.. before forwarding to a client. If this can't be done CV's dont get forwarded
- **Reformatting**: Some consultancies reformat a candidates CV to comply with corporate guidelines before sending to a client, they need word for this.

**Possible quick solution:**
Since word 2007 it's been possible to create a word document from html in a couple of lines of code without automating word. Essentially you create an HTML file (Package part) in the word package and create a pointer to the inserted part.

When the document is opened by word it's rendered normally as word content

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc =
WordprocessingDocument.Open("Test1.docx", true))
{
    string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
    AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
        AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open("TestInsertedContent.docx", FileMode.Open))
        chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
    altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
    mainPart.Document
        .Body
        .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
    mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```

Source: [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericwhite/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly)

I really love the careers site, but without supporting word it will make it a lot harder for me to use.

**Update** : 03/10/2011
Talking to a global recruitment agency this morning, they told me they reformatted all candidate CV's into a 'common' company template [sigh] before forwarding to clients. If given a CV in PDF format they still performed this operation but it took them much longer.

I've also noticed that some job boards will

- not allow you to upload PDF's
- or they restrict file size to 500KB (my CV in pdf format is 500kb and only 130kb in doc format)

Comment: In the UK word is expected,  I tend to turn on change tracking, then hide the changes bar, so any project manger that wishes can see what changes the agent has made.

Comment: I too have noticed job boards which do not allow anything other than word formats.  While I prefere .pdf, I would like the option for Word in addition.

Comment: That recruiters prefer Word is also my experience. It would be very useful if there was an "Export as DOCX"-feature similar to export to pdf.

Answer (score 6):

I was always under the impression that it was good to use PDF when sending in your resumé (CV) but your arguments are compelling in favor of a Word format.
I also applaud your 'quickfix' which should be useful to the development team should this proposal be accepted.